# While running TestNG program in eclipse getting error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, testng

Getting JNI error while running TestNG program (that doesn't have main() function). 
But If trying to run the same program with same set of configuration (i.e. eclipse and java version), "Run as a java application" then it's working fine.

After click on OK button on the pop up of "JNI error", getting below error-
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException**

[image: Java and Javac version]

Comment: Is this resolved ?

Comment: Yes, this is resolved. We can close this.